# How to build and bundle a single package with Turbopack

Tags: turborepo, turbopack

It is advertised that [Turbopack is a successor to Webpack](https://turbo.build/pack).

I have a monorepo where one of the TS packages needs to be built and bundled for Node.js and deployed to Firebase. Previously I was doing this with Webpack but now that I'm migrating to Turborepo I would like to use Turbopack for this.

I can't find any instructions on how to build and bundle a single package. The Turborepo examples appear to use other tools like `tsup` or `esbuild` to build and/or bundle other packages besides NextJS apps.

It seems odd that these tools would still be needed given the description on the Turbopack website.

Comment: I use tsup inside of my turborepo setup. I don't know if turbopack is yet meant to be used in the same way, but documentation still seems lacking at this point

Comment: Nice and thank you for your response. I got this resolved by adding the package names to the [transpilePackages](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/transpilePackages) inside the `next.config.js` file.

Comment: Ah yes, if your only target is NextJS that's a very convenient feature. Good to hear that you found your solution.